Difference between adding a requires expression to a concept and not adding one in C++
I found when I using a concept with requires expression, the compiler won't match the constraints but report an ambiguous error. After replace the requires expression to a common expression, it actually passed the compile. What is the difference between adding a requires expression to a concept and not adding one ?
Here is the demo code:
#include <cstdint>

class uint63;

template<typename T>
/*
// this got error
concept is_not_uint63_t = requires {
    !std::same_as<T, uint63>;
};
*/
// and this pass the compile
concept is_not_uint63_t = !std::same_as<T, uint63>;


class uint63 {
    template<is_not_uint63_t T>
    friend uint63 operator +(T t, uint63 u) {
        return u.container_ + static_cast<uint64_t>(t);
    }

private:
    uint64_t container_;
public:
    uint63(uint64_t u) : container_(u) {}
    operator uint64_t () {
        return this->container_;
    }
    template<typename T> uint63 operator +(T n) const { return { this->container_ + static_cast<uint64_t>(n) }; }
};
int main() {
    uint63 k = 1;
    uint63 w = k + 1;
    uint63 r = k + w;
}

The error message(With clang++ 17 on Ubuntu22.04):
error: use of overloaded operator '+' is ambiguous (with operand types 'uint63' and 'uint63')
   28 |     uint63 r = k + w;


Always post complete error along  with your question.

You need nested requires.

You misunderstand what a requires expression is used for. From cppreference:

The substitution of template arguments into a requires-expression used in a declaration of a templated entity may result in the formation of invalid types or expressions in its requirements, or the violation of semantic constraints of those requirements. In such cases, the requires-expression evaluates to false and does not cause the program to be ill-formed. The substitution and semantic constraint checking proceeds in lexical order and stops when a condition that determines the result of the requires-expression is encountered. If substitution (if any) and semantic constraint checking succeed, the requires-expression evaluates to true.

In other words, requires { !std::same_as<T, uint63>; }; checks the same thing as requires { std::same_as<T, uint63>; }; does. !std::same_as<T,uint63> is a valid expression for any type T. Hence, any type satisfies the concept.
On the other hand, this
concept is_not_uint63_t = !std::same_as<T, uint63>; 

Evaluates to true when T and uint63 are the same type, and false otherwise.
What you are actually looking for is a Nested Requirement:
requires { requires !std::same_as<T, uint63>; };

For why and how this does what you want I refer you to the cppreference site.
